# Edittext: Change background image when start typing

Tags: android

I have used background image for edittext and i want that when i start typing it should change. How to do it???

I have used:

```
editText_username.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
editText_password.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(editText_username.hasFocus()){
        editText_username.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textarea_blue);
    }else{
        editText_username.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textarea_gray);
    }
    if(editText_password.hasFocus()){
        editText_password.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textarea_blue);
    }else{
        editText_password.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textarea_gray);
    }
   }
```

edittext background images is changing. But when i first click on username edittext the background image is not changing and when i click password edittext image is changing and again when i click on username edittext now the image is changing...Why is it so? I want that when i click username edittext for the first time background image is changed at that time only and also when click outside editext the color shoukd return to default color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
editText_username.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         //change bg afterTextChanged
  }

  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
         //change bg beforeTextChanged
  }

  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
         //change bg whenTextChanged
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Focus changed is just to identify that the EditText is focused of not. You should use [Text Watcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

Answer (score 0):

Simply Add a selector as a background, and put your special background with status focused true

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/edit_text_bg_pressed" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/edit_text_bg_normal" />

</selector>
```